# How to make 2 queries execute as one

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 queries that i want to execute as one

```
ALTER TABLE X ADD Y INT

UPDATE X SET Y = Z
```

When i select them both to execute shows

```
Invalid column name Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compiler error. Both the statements are valid, however, the entire batch is compiled first, prior to any execution. As a result, the entire batch fails as before the statements are executed the column `Y` does not exist in the table `X`. Though the compiler is "clever" enough to defer the validation for some objects (for example you can `CREATE` and then `INSERT` into a `TABLE` in the same batch) this is not true for things like when you `ALTER` a `TABLE` to add a `COLUMN`.

The "simple" solution would be to put the 2 statements into 2 batches. In an IDE-like application such as SSMS or ADS, you can use `GO` to separate your statements:

```sql
ALTER TABLE X ADD Y INT NULL;
GO
UPDATE X SET Y = Z;
```

If they must be in the same batch, you can defer the compilation of the second statement. One method would be to execute the statement with `sys.sp_executesql`. This would mean that the statement executed by the procedure would not be compiled until `sys.sp_executesql` itself is executed; which is *after* the table was `ALTER`ed:

```sql
ALTER TABLE X ADD Y INT NULL;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'UPDATE X SET Y = Z;';
```